# Проблема с вставкой русского nvarchar текста из базы данных в русский utf-8 текст

Tags: sql, perl, utf-8

ActiveState PERL 5.14

MS SQL server 2008

Я читаю русский UTF-8 текст из файла

```
open(HTML, "<:utf8", $template_file)
```

Считываю в переменную через DBD:ODBC русский текст из nvarchar поля в таблице на SQL Server.
Конвертирую эту переменную через модуль Encode в "UTF-8".
Если я просто выдаю эту переменную на print(), то в бровзере текст читается по-русски.
Но мне надо добавить текст, взятый из базы данных, в текст, взятый из файла, и записать в другой файл.
И я его записываю, и весь текст там русский, кроме того, который я вставил из переменной - он превращается во что-то вроде " ÃÂ·Ã" (если я использовал для текста из базы encode("UTF-8")) или "Ð Â·Ð Ñ" (если не использовал).

Comment: Что-то не так у вас с флагом UTF8 при чтении из базы. Видимо происходит двойная перекодировка. Попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](http://xpoint.ru/know-how/Perl/PodderzhkaUnicode) и [здесь](https://ivan.bessarabov.ru/blog/perl-unicode)

Comment: hobo-mts прав. Как мне засчитать комментарий за ответ?

Comment: Честно говоря, я не знаю. Не получится -- не расстроюсь

Comment: Так напишите ж свой ответ ниже, а я его приму.

Comment: Не считаю свой комментарий полноценным ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, вы зря конвертируете прочитанный из базы текст в ютф-8. Тут еще надо разобраться с терминологией. Есть методы encode и decode. 
Первый - принимает символы и преобразует в байты. Как известно, юникодные символы могут быть за пределами байта. Это иногда нужно для вывода.
Второй - наоборот принимает байты и преобразует в символы.
Так вот, перл работает с символами, а при чтении из базы именно символы и читаются. А значит никакие методы из модуля Encode тут применять не нужно. При правильном чтении из файла (open my $handle, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $name) вы так-же получите символы. Работайте с ними без лишних трансформаций.
Для вывода в браузер опять таки ничего не делайте, только укажите в заголовке кодировку (Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8).
Для сохранения в файл есть два варианта. Или прогнать строки через encode, или открыть файл для записи через "open my $handle, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $name;".